# Usando PING com PHP

Tags: php, ping

Tenho uma função que precisa pingar 5 máquinas na rede interna. Estou usando o comando abaixo:

```
 //EXECUTA O PING
 exec("ping " . $host, $output, $result);
```

O que ocorre é o seguinte. Se eu coloco um ip qualquer, fora do padrão, como "192.999.999.999" o teste da função, abaixo, retorna corretamente que não existe (OFF):

```
// TESTA O RESULTADO
if ($result == 0) {
  echo "ON";
} else {
  echo "OFF";
}
```

Agora, se eu coloco um ip correto, mas que somente esteja offline, ele me retorna sempre ON. Se o ip está mesmo online ele também me retorna ON, o que é correto.

Existe alguma outra forma de usar esse ping no PHP? De forma que ele reconheça quando o ip está offline?

Comment: Estranho ele retornar ON já que tecnicamente o ping só conseguiria retornar um IP que estivesse ligado a rede, vou fazer alguns testes aqui e retornarei com algo em breve.

Comment: Quando você "pinga" nesse computador *offline*, qual é valor da variável `result`? veja: `var_dump($result);`. Outra coisa, o teu SO é Windows?

Comment: Sim, é Windows. Na real já resolvi o problema, adicionar a resposta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Editei o comando `exec`, adicionando o seguinte:

```
exec("ping -n 1 -w 1 " . $host, $output, $result);
```

Dessa forma, além de ganhar tempo, o resultado passou a ser correto.

Answer (score 2):

Tente da seguinte maneira:

```
exec('ping 127.0.0.1', $saida, $retorno);
if (count($saida)) {
    print 'A Máquina está online e os dados do PING foram gravados em $saida. :)';
} else {
    print 'A Máquina NÃO está online ou o host não pode ser encontrado. :(';
}
```

Comment: Não, a máquina esta offline e ele aparece como on.