# Validação de página com PHP e JAVASCRIPT

Tags: php, javascript, redes

Então eu faço redes de computadores e estou o último semestre, estamos realizando um TCC aonde irá funcionar da seguinte forma:

Uma rede Mesh para zonas afastadas que não possuem acesso a internet, com isso quem estiver conectado a esta rede conseguirá assistir filmes, ouvir músicas, conversar via texto e voz, etc.

Estou com a tarefa de criar uma community page aonde o pessoal vai acessar o  link e vai ter o botão das aplicações que será redirecionado para a aplicação e o problema se encontra ai.

Preciso realizar a validação para ver se o IP/DNS está no ar ou não, porém fazer isso no front-end não é 100% de certeza pois tem várias contraditórias pois uma página web offline pode ser várias coisas que só emite um HTTP, com isso estou fazendo no PHP, porém não estou conseguindo realizar a "junção" do javascript com o PHP, veja:

Chamando a function Javascript:

```
            document.getElementById('plex').addEventListener('click', () => checagemplex());
```

Função:

```
            function checagemplex () {
            var checar = <?php
                if (!fsockopen("192.168.1.145", 80, $errno, $errstr, 10)) {
                    echo "Offline";
                } else {
                   echo "Online"; 
                }
            ?>;

            $.ajax({
                checar;
            }).done(function() { 
                alert('Online');
            }).fail(function() { 
                alert('Offline');
            })
        }
```

Alguém já esteve nessa situação e sabe alguma forma para melhorar a função de checagem e fazer com que a mesma funcione?

Obrigado!

Comment: acredito que a melhor forma seria tu usar pelo proprio php um ping: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/158466/usando-ping-com-php

Answer (score -1):

Eu até tentei fazer dessa forma:

```
        <input type="button" value="TESTE" id="buttonx">
    <script>
        function checkplex () {
            var check = <?php 
                    exec('ping 127.0.0.1', $saida, $retorno);
                    if (count($saida)) {
                        print 'A Máquina está online e os dados do PING foram gravados em $saida. :)';
                    } else {
                        print 'A Máquina NÃO está online ou o host não pode ser encontrado. :(';
                    }
                ?>
            document.write(check);  
        }
        document.getElementById('buttonx').addEventListener('click', () => checkplex());
    </script>
```

Mesmo assim, não funcionou, a chamada do button eu só consigo fazer em client-side preciso fazer essa combinação do PHP com JS, rs.

Obrigado pela força, mas ainda não consegui estou pesquisando e vendo se encontro algo